# Understanding jQuery Ajax Callback Error Issue when using Webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, linq, web-services

In my asp.net web application I'm using jquery ajax to to pass a value to a ASMX webservice which then using an SQL to LINQ dataclass inserts some values that are calculated within the webservice.  Nothing is / or needs to returned to the calling ajax. All I'm doing is inserting values into my sql database via the webservice.

Everything works as expected - the value is passed to the webservice and the webservice is properly inserting the values into my sql table.   The issue is when I set the ajax async value to true the ajax error function ends up being called and returns an error status value of 0.  None the less, in this case the webservice still inserted its values into the sql table correctly.

If I change the ajax async value to false the webservice once again successfully does its job and the Ajax function in this case calls the successful callback function.   So although this technically is working by inserting the values into the dbase from the webservice why does trying to use ajax async equal to true cause ajax to call the error function?

I'm obviously not understanding some aspect of this process.  So the end result is the same no matter if I use async or not.    Of course, I could change the async value to false but I guess this all boils down to my concern that using async true is causing me to lose or introduce other unknown issues.  Is it something with how I have the ajax function setup or something with the webservice itself? Help me understand where or what is going on here.  Thanks so much for trying to connect the dots in my head on this one.

Here are the key parts -

jQuery ajax -

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'WebService.asmx/CalledMethod',
    data: "{'myURL':'" + myUrl + "'}",
    datatype: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function(msg)
    {
        if (msg != true) {
           alert(msg);
        }
    },

    error: function(jqXhr, status, error)
    {
        alert(jqXhr.status)

        }); // 
    } 
});
```

The WebService -

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempurimayo.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void CallMethod(string myURL)
    {
        {              

                using (var myLog = new MyDataClassDataContext()
                {

                    var Entry = new myLogTable
                    {
                        Date = DateTime.Now,                            
                        Url = Uri.UnescapeDataString(myURL)

                    };

                    // insert record into log table
                    RecordsToInsert.myLogTables.InsertOnSubmit(Entry);
                    RecordsToInsert.SubmitChanges();                       
                }                       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you change the return type to `bool` and pass back true?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  A few things.  Before following your suggestion I hadn't tried using IE in a while so I fired that up.  Using IE 8 and IE 10 the successful function was being called! Weird.  Using the latest chrome the Error function continues to be called.  I then tried your suggestion and nothing changed.  IE 8 / 10 called the Successful function and Chrome still calls the Error function.